# Can I get the name of my object in C#?

Tags: c#

Let us say I have the following class..

```
Class Boy
{
    public void hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
            Boy a = new Boy();
            a.hello();
    }
}
```

I know that the variable **'a'** is a reference variable of type **'Boy'**. The keyword **'new'** created an object of **'Boy'** assigning the address of it to the variable **'a'**.

Now, is it possible for me to get the name of my object. Does an object in C# have a name at all ?

Comment: What do you mean by "name"? The name of the class `Boy`, the name of the variable `a`? Something else?

Comment: If you could say, what you need this for, or what you imply, saying *name*, you would probably get a better answer.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, Blorgbeard I asked if I can get the name of my object. I am sure everyone who marked my question as 'unresearched' or 'useless' either didn't understand my question or don't know what an object is...

Comment: ranjith, so what is the name of the object?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov I never dwelled on OOPs concepts.. got this doubt while practicing, so was curious to know the answer from some experts here..

Comment: @ranjith please don't assume that anyone who disagrees with you is ignorant. Now: in your example, what *do you think* the "name" is?

Comment: @MarcGravell sorry marc, I didn't mean that.. just didn't like people rejecting my question within mins of posting it.. by 'name' i was referring to the name of the object, if anything like that can be retrieved/found out.. Thanks.. [I don't know the answer.. so requesting if anyone knows]

Comment: @ranjith, you never answered what I asked you. Marc Gravell is asking the same...

Comment: @Ranjith again, and for the last time: what do you think the name is? "a"? "Boy"? or....?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? You can get a method name from within an object or object's getter System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name it makes sense that one might want to get a "name" of a property. It is a good question even if the answer is NO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get instance name c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363753/get-instance-name-c-sharp). As that question was slightly clearer & specifically stated that the OP wanted the name of the reference to the object, I propose we make this question a dupe of that one and not the other way around, even though this question is much older.

Comment: For the record, I have always wished there were a way to do this, although I understand the reasons why we can't.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm guessing you are referring to the name of the variable, "a". Well, the thing is: that *isn't* the name of the object - objects don't have names. Further, an object can have zero one or multiple references to it, for example:

```
var x = new SomeType(); // a class
var y = x;
```

Here both x and y refer to the same object. Equally:

```
new SomeType();
```

doesn't have any references to it, but is still an object. Additionally, method variables (locals) don't actually have names in IL - only in c# (for contrast, fields do have names). So `new SomeType().WriteName();` would make no sense.

So no: there is no sane way of getting the name of the variable from an object reference.

If you want the object to have a name, add a `Name` property.

There are some fun ways to get the name of a variable of field using expression trees, but I don't think that is useful to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 18):

```
class Boy
{
    public void hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Boy a = new Boy();
        a.hello();
        Type objtype = a.GetType();
        Console.WriteLine(objtype.Name); // this will display "Boy"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We don't have a name of objects. In fact object's reference is assigned to the *reference* variable in order to access *data* via public methods/properties. If you wish to have the reference of an object within the `instance` method of that particular class then use `this` variable.

```
Class Boy
{   
    int age;
    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age; 
    }
}
```