# Get name of variable that holds instance of a class

Tags: vb.net

See my code. It is working, it writes to debug InstanceName of a Class2 instance (the name is Test).
I want to change my code so that in Class Form1 instead of line  `Test = New Class2(NameOf(Test))` there will be line `Test = New Class2()`.
And assigning the InstanceName will be made automatically in the Sub New in the Class2. So that the Sub New would look something like this:

```
Sub New()
    Me.InstanceName = **???Me.GetParent.Name???**
End Sub
```

Now this is the working example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Test As Class2
        Test = New Class2(NameOf(Test))
        Debug.WriteLine($"InstanceName: {Test.InstanceName}")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Class2
    Public Property InstanceName
    Sub New(InstanceName_ As String)
        Me.InstanceName = InstanceName_
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What's the use of this? -- `Test` is not the *name of the instance*, it's the name of a local variable.

Comment: @Jimi I want to to the use of this too. But I'm not sure what the *name of the instance* would be other than "Test" here. I would say the working version is the best and only way, even see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16363753/832052) which we might even mark as a duplicate, and is almost identical to the working version. For OP's purposes, I think the term *name of the instance* is fine

Comment: @djv variables don't have names outside the context where they have been declared. If you pass your Test object to another Sub - `Sub Hello(world As Class2)` for example - that instance would now be named `world`.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville I understand, but that's just a reference to the same memory location the variable Test originally pointed to. In this example Test goes out of scope after Form_Load then the new reference, world, would be the only one. I guess Test is important to OP in some diagnostic way, and I would say the working example he has is the best [only] way to do this.